# how to identify which user has executed the commands through history command

Tags: rhel

I have got a requirement to identify which user has executed what commands in the history. when I type history, the commands should come with date,time and user. how this can be achieved?

Comment: The `history` command only shows commands for the current user. So there is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember, `history` command displays the current user's history. That means, one user can't see other user's history.

Please login as `root` user

Execute the following command

`grep -e "$pattern" /home/*/.bash_history`

If you have multiple users then the username will be displayed as `/home/username`

**Sample Output:**

```
/home/testuser1/.bash_history:ls
/home/testuser2/.bash_history:pwd
```

**How to see time stamps in bash history**

Please execute the following command to see the date, time in history command

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

Then please type `history` command

**Sample output**

```
root@system:~# history
   67  02/04/18 19:25:03 echo 'hi'
   68  02/04/18 19:25:03 ls -l
   69  02/04/18 19:25:03 pwd
   70  02/04/18 19:25:03 ifconfig
```

Comment: thank you. this command worked "grep -e "$pattern" /home/*/.bash_history" . but I got the output as below.
    
/home/digadm01/.bash_history:#1518070986
/home/digadm01/.bash_history:cd
/home/digadm01/.bash_history:#1518070991
/home/digadm01/.bash_history:crontab -l
/home/digadm01/.bash_history:#1518070995
/home/digadm01/.bash_history:crontab -e

here :#1518070995 is the date in the encrypted format. how to change this. so that it should show the timestamp

Comment: if this answer solves your problem, then please accept this answer by clicking the accept button.